# unable to install coursera course with coursera-dl c

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, python-3.11, visual-studio-code-server

I successfully installed coursera-dll from git hub using visual studio code and python 3.11 but i can not download coursera course

This is the code I entered:

`coursera-dl -ca S8DQ3UGxlhuEGyOt_0AYUZr8n5UuoXMQcaPwi5VTJcuf0FeBouSO4gGTBXP0Nz8zEfMESoikTzUpFv5wI5bo5w.KZ2IWaTymHa178n8SQ2A3A.xTOjp9cOt4lLHlQ-lfBb0vaoYLsLDuaCBE_OUpZFwloU-6O0SFgufAWHsylK6fA1OGMzz-JorHeYrmFyxXAzQShOWw-QHCdNlA0cI9FZB89V1dHzlxjzNXFB96ynnE46_195GYV0OuabyV4A29QCuMQdt3tj0Z65YkFIx1Qt7PqK3qfmy6P0_p1ugTYWokOsWG4ekjy3qepGegnUOkB-nDYhy6Net1JMBWHnz7Sb8i38Gem9l1S_Qxc5Dnv8KNyMLX1xVej8mdDj_IWwMdTe2c_ob_9t0adwFfFuCA_5HG5tCyOcTVTZNGVsdsOWhPl3J0r5xYpLNLxZCQCjN7-8iVokjDXbcMHe4MiC0RiIQuS5wdTIVUjH7aP6aFGuVYQx6f-YCajVRz9zlzJ3noSqRItMWxioW0F4GpcvRhPvC4FbNFXP3gWYUwMkGEU5pHGDWGqkVCRju2BM2lGf-_x1DFuYm0g5FqFlKnZDuhg31NY database-clients`

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\Program Files\Scripts\coursera-dl-script.py", line 33, in <module>
sys.exit(load_entry_point('coursera==0.5.2', 'console_scripts', 'coursera-dl')())` 
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
nt
return next(matches).load()
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "D:\Program Files\Lib\importlib\metadata_`_`init`_`_.py", line 202, in load
module = import_module(match.group('module'))
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "D:\Program Files\Lib\importlib_`_`init`_`_.py", line 126, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1206, in _gcd_import
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1178, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1149, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 690, in _load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 940, in exec_module
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
File "D:\Program Files\Lib\site-packages\coursera\coursera_dl.py", line 58, in <module>` 
import six
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'six'
PS D:\coursera-courses\coursera-dl-1> pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall coursera-dl

> > 

Collecting coursera-dl
Downloading coursera_dl-0.11.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl (68 kB)
━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 68.8/68.8 kB 537.3 kB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting beautifulsoup4>=4.1.3
Downloading beautifulsoup4-4.11.2-py3-none-any.whl (129 kB)
━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 129.4/129.4 kB 1.3 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting requests>=2.10.0
Downloading requests-2.28.2-py3-none-any.whl (62 kB)
━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 62.8/62.8 kB 3.3 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting six>=1.5.0
Downloading six-1.16.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (11 kB)
Collecting urllib3>=1.23
Downloading urllib3-1.26.15-py2.py3-none-any.whl (140 kB)
━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 140.9/140.9 kB 2.8 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting pyasn1>=0.1.7
Downloading pyasn1-0.4.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl (77 kB)
━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 77.1/77.1 kB ? eta 0:00:00
Collecting keyring>=4.0
Downloading keyring-23.13.1-py3-none-any.whl (37 kB)
Collecting configargparse>=0.12.0
Downloading ConfigArgParse-1.5.3-py3-none-any.whl (20 kB)
Collecting attrs==18.1.0
Downloading attrs-18.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (28 kB)
Collecting soupsieve>1.2
Downloading soupsieve-2.4-py3-none-any.whl (37 kB)
Collecting jaraco.classes
Downloading jaraco.classes-3.2.3-py3-none-any.whl (6.0 kB)
Collecting importlib-metadata>=4.11.4
Downloading importlib_metadata-6.1.0-py3-none-any.whl (21 kB)
Collecting pywin32-ctypes>=0.2.0
Downloading pywin32_ctypes-0.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (28 kB)
Collecting charset-normalizer<4,>=2
Downloading charset_normalizer-3.1.0-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl (96 kB)
━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 96.7/96.7 kB 5.8 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting idna<4,>=2.5
Downloading idna-3.4-py3-none-any.whl (61 kB)
━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 61.5/61.5 kB 3.4 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting certifi>=2017.4.17
Downloading certifi-2022.12.7-py3-none-any.whl (155 kB)
━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 155.3/155.3 kB 3.1 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting zipp>=0.5
Downloading zipp-3.15.0-py3-none-any.whl (6.8 kB)
Collecting more-itertools
Downloading more_itertools-9.1.0-py3-none-any.whl (54 kB)
━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 54.2/54.2 kB 1.4 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Installing collected packages: pywin32-ctypes, pyasn1, attrs, zipp, urllib3, soupsieve, six,
more-itertools, idna, configargparse, charset-normalizer, certifi, requests, jaraco.classes,
importlib-metadata, beautifulsoup4, keyring, coursera-dl
Attempting uninstall: pywin32-ctypes
Found existing installation: pywin32-ctypes 0.2.0
Uninstalling pywin32-ctypes-0.2.0:
Successfully uninstalled pywin32-ctypes-0.2.0
Attempting uninstall: pyasn1
Found existing installation: pyasn1 0.4.8
Uninstalling pyasn1-0.4.8:
Successfully uninstalled pyasn1-0.4.8
Attempting uninstall: attrs
Found existing installation: attrs 18.1.0
Uninstalling attrs-18.1.0:
Successfully uninstalled attrs-18.1.0
Attempting uninstall: zipp
Found existing installation: zipp 3.15.0
Uninstalling zipp-3.15.0:
Successfully uninstalled zipp-3.15.0
Attempting uninstall: urllib3
Found existing installation: urllib3 1.26.15
Uninstalling urllib3-1.26.15:
Successfully uninstalled urllib3-1.26.15
Attempting uninstall: soupsieve
Found existing installation: soupsieve 2.4
Uninstalling soupsieve-2.4:
Successfully uninstalled soupsieve-2.4
Attempting uninstall: more-itertools
Found existing installation: more-itertools 9.1.0
Uninstalling more-itertools-9.1.0:
Successfully uninstalled more-itertools-9.1.0
Attempting uninstall: idna
Found existing installation: idna 3.4
Uninstalling idna-3.4:
Successfully uninstalled idna-3.4
Attempting uninstall: configargparse
Found existing installation: ConfigArgParse 1.5.3
Uninstalling ConfigArgParse-1.5.3:
Successfully uninstalled ConfigArgParse-1.5.3
Attempting uninstall: charset-normalizer
Found existing installation: charset-normalizer 3.1.0
Uninstalling charset-normalizer-3.1.0:
Successfully uninstalled charset-normalizer-3.1.0
Attempting uninstall: certifi
Found existing installation: certifi 2022.12.7
Uninstalling certifi-2022.12.7:
Successfully uninstalled certifi-2022.12.7
Attempting uninstall: requests
Found existing installation: requests 2.28.2
Uninstalling requests-2.28.2:
Successfully uninstalled requests-2.28.2
Attempting uninstall: jaraco.classes
Found existing installation: jaraco.classes 3.2.3
Uninstalling jaraco.classes-3.2.3:
Successfully uninstalled jaraco.classes-3.2.3
Attempting uninstall: importlib-metadata
Found existing installation: importlib-metadata 6.0.0
Uninstalling importlib-metadata-6.0.0:
Successfully uninstalled importlib-metadata-6.0.0
Attempting uninstall: beautifulsoup4
Found existing installation: beautifulsoup4 4.11.2
Uninstalling beautifulsoup4-4.11.2:
Successfully uninstalled beautifulsoup4-4.11.2
Attempting uninstall: keyring
Found existing installation: keyring 23.13.1
Uninstalling keyring-23.13.1:
Successfully uninstalled keyring-23.13.1
Attempting uninstall: coursera-dl
Found existing installation: coursera-dl 0.11.5
Uninstalling coursera-dl-0.11.5:
Successfully uninstalled coursera-dl-0.11.5
ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
pytest 7.2.2 requires colorama; sys_platform == "win32", which is not installed.
pytest 7.2.2 requires packaging, which is not installed.
pytest 7.2.2 requires attrs>=19.2.0, but you have attrs 18.1.0 which is incompatible.` 
Successfully installed attrs-18.1.0 beautifulsoup4-4.11.2 certifi-2022.12.7 charset-normalizer-3.1.0 configargparse-1.5.3 coursera-dl-0.11.5 idna-3.4 importlib-metadata-6.1.0 jaraco.classes-3.2.3 keyring-23.13.1 more-itertools-9.1.0 pyasn1-0.4.8 pywin32-ctypes-0.2.0 requests-2.28.2 six-1.16.0 soupsieve-2.4 urllib3-1.26.15 zipp-3.15.0
```

I tried this code:

`coursera-dl -ca S8DQ3UGxlhuEGyOt_0AYUZr8n5UuoXMQcaPwi5VTJcuf0FeBouSO4gGTBXP0Nz8zEfMESoikTzUpFv5wI5bo5w.KZ2IWaTymHa178n8SQ2A3A.xTOjp9cOt4lLHlQ-lfBb0vaoYLsLDuaCBE_OUpZFwloU-6O0SFgufAWHsylK6fA1OGMzz-JorHeYrmFyxXAzQShOWw-QHCdNlA0cI9FZB89V1dHzlxjzNXFB96ynnE46_195GYV0OuabyV4A29QCuMQdt3tj0Z65YkFIx1Qt7PqK3qfmy6P0_p1ugTYWokOsWG4ekjy3qepGegnUOkB-nDYhy6Net1JMBWHnz7Sb8i38Gem9l1S_Qxc5Dnv8KNyMLX1xVej8mdDj_IWwMdTe2c_ob_9t0adwFfFuCA_5HG5tCyOcTVTZNGVsdsOWhPl3J0r5xYpLNLxZCQCjN7-8iVokjDXbcMHe4MiC0RiIQuS5wdTIVUjH7aP6aFGuVYQx6f-YCajVRz9zlzJ3noSqRItMWxioW0F4GpcvRhPvC4FbNFXP3gWYUwMkGEU5pHGDWGqkVCRju2BM2lGf-_x1DFuYm0g5FqFlKnZDuhg31NY database-clients`

and I expect to download the course databae-clients to my pc

Answer (score 1):

```
pytest 7.2.2 requires colorama; sys_platform == "win32", which is not installed.
pytest 7.2.2 requires packaging, which is not installed.
pytest 7.2.2 requires attrs>=19.2.0, but you have attrs 18.1.0 which is incompatible.`
```

Installing these packages as needed and downloading coursera-dll from github again can solve this problem.

Comment: thank you for your answer .. can you please give me a link to these so that i can download it and install it

Comment: @samehsaad Hi, you can use command `pip install packageName` in your terminal to install the python packages.

Comment: I installed the packagename and reinstalled coursera-dl then typed the code with the new CAUTH code but anoter error appeared .. can you give me your email address so that i can sent you the error .. i can not post it in the comment .. please sent me something to my email .. ..  (engineersamehsaad87@gamil.com)